# squid 3.1.11-1 - POST issues

Tags: proxy, http-proxy, squid

I have an issue with my squid on the website : http://www.draw.io
I have one schema and I am not able to export it as a PNG (I got a white page on the web browser like the website didn't answer.)

Without using squid export is working fine.

I look at the logs and here is what I found :
When not working I got :
1376985774.106      0 127.0.0.1 TCP_DENIED/407 4366 POST http://exp.draw.io/ImageExport2/export - NONE/- text/html

When I delete some stuff on my design it works :

TCP_MISS/200 76269 POST http://exp.draw.io/ImageExport2/export hugo
@domain.LOCAL DIRECT/199.38.86.62 application/x-unknown

For me it seems related to the post size. Should I modify something in my squid configuration ? (which is pretty basic).

Answer (score 0):

Your working request log has NTLM information included "hugo @domain.LOCAL".  A 407 response is the server requesting proxy auth information as the headers are missing from the request.

You need to supply the auth information from your client as it appears to not support adding the information dynamically if you are just getting a blank page.

Comment: I don't really understand as I have this issue with all web browser  : chrome, firefox and IE. Why smaller file is ok with NTLM and not bigger one ?

Answer (score 0):

Your working request log has NTLM information included"hugo@domain. regional". A 407 response is the waiter requesting agent auth information as the captions are missing from the request.

You need to supply the auth information from your guest as it appears to not support adding the information energetically if you're just getting a blank page.